# How to prevent sbt from running integration tests?

Tags: junit, sbt, scalatest

Maven surefire-plugin doesn't run integration tests (they named with "IT" suffix by convention), but sbt runs both: unit and integration. So, how to prevent this behaviour? Is there a common way to distinguish integration and unit tests for ScalaTest (don't run  FeatureSpec-tests by default)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How to do that is exactly documented on the sbt manual on http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#additional-test-configurations-with-shared-sources :

```
//Build.scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

object B extends Build {
  lazy val root =
    Project("root", file("."))
      .configs( FunTest )
      .settings( inConfig(FunTest)(Defaults.testTasks) : _*)
      .settings(
         libraryDependencies += specs,
         testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter(itFilter)),
         testOptions in FunTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(unitFilter))
         )

  def itFilter(name: String): Boolean = name endsWith "ITest"
  def unitFilter(name: String): Boolean = (name endsWith "Test") && !itFilter(name)

  lazy val FunTest = config("fun") extend(Test)
  lazy val specs = "org.scala-tools.testing" %% "specs" % "1.6.8" % "test"
}
```

Call `sbt test` for unit tests and `sbt fun:test` for integration test and `sbt test fun:test` for both.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way with the latest sbt is just to apply `IntegrationTest` config and corresponding settings as described [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#integration-tests), - and you put your tests in `src/it/scala` directory in your project.